# Comparar um vetor do tipo char?

Tags: c, array, char

Bom pessoal tenho a seguinte duvida por quê não consigo comparar dois vetores do tipo char usando operadores relacionais ? Eu sei que vetores são um tipo composto e que os caracteres estão em uma área estática estou certo ?

Mas afinal o que influencia na hora da comparação sabendo que vetor e composto e que a string esta em uma área estática?

Answer (score 1):

"Não consegue" fazer a comparação com operadores relacionais pois as variáveis que representam os vetores são ponteiros para os seus primeiros elementos.

Por esse motivo quando compara por exemplo com `==` está a comparar se os ponteiros tem o mesmo valor, ou seja, apontam para o mesmo local na memoria. Isso só irá acontecer se forem o mesmo vetor. Em relação ao facto de estarem ou não numa área estática não vai influenciar em nada a comparação.

Considere o seguinte exemplo:

```
char texto1[] = "um texto";
char texto2[] = "um texto";

printf("\n%d", texto1 == texto2); //0 - que representa falso

char *texto3 = texto1;
printf("\n%d", texto1 == texto3); //1 - que representa verdadeiro
```

No ultimo exemplo `texto3` foi um ponteiro que coloquei manualmente a apontar para o vetor `texto1`.

Em contraste, comparar com `<=` ou `>=` apenas lhe vai dizer se um ponteiro é maior que o outro, que não é util.

A comparação deve então ser feita com um laço/ciclo, que passa a cada letra e faz a comparação entre cada vetor. Utilizando uma versão bem simples poderia fazer assim:

```
int compara_strings(char str1[], char str2[]){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; str1[i] != '\0' && str2[i] != '\0'; i++){
        //assim que uma letra seja diferente
        if (str1[i] != str2[i]){ 
            //retorna -1 se a primeira for menor ou 1 caso contrário
            return str1[i] < str2[i] ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }
    //Se as duas acabaram, são iguais e retorna 0. Se a str1 acabou e str2 não
    //retorna um valor negativo. Se str2 acabou e a str1 retorna um valor positivo
    return str1[i] - str2[i];
}
```

Repare que aqui os retornos tem significados especificos:

- 0 - strings iguais
- negativo - primeira string menor que a segunda
- positivo - primeira string maior que a segunda

Quando se diz que uma string é maior ou menor, é uma comparação lexicográfica (alfabética).

No entanto estaria a reinventar a roda pois já existe uma função para fazer esta mesma comparação em `<string.h>` que se chama [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

Utilizar essa função no exemplo inicial seria:

```
char texto1[] = "um texto";
char texto2[] = "um texto";

printf("\n%d", strcmp(texto1,texto2)); //0 - que representa iguais
```

Comment: A muito bem explicado,  tinha esquecido desse fato de que o nome do vetor e na verdade um endereço de memória referente ao seu primeiro índice o 0..